# NodeJS and mongodb unable to get result with large amounts of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am not getting any response from mongodb when I query large amounts of documents.

Is this a callback issue? or a configuration issue? All I am trying to do is count the number of documents according to the specified query.

My code for querying mongo:

```
 /*jslint node:true */
'use strict';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cse541';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    var collection = db.collection("flights"), cursor = collection.find({year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1});

    collection.find({year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1}).count(function (err, number) {
        console.log(number);
        db.close();
    });


    //cursor.limit(1);
    /*
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (doc != null) {
            console.log('Fetched:', doc);
        } else {
            db.close();
        }
    });
    */

});
```

Output when using count:

```
PS C:\Users\Frank\Documents\CSE 541\Project\flightdelaytracker> node serverside

null
```

Output when using the cursor in the code:

```
PS C:\Users\Frank\Documents\CSE 541\Project\flightdelaytracker> node serverside

{ MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Frank\Documents\CSE 541\Project\flightdelaytracker\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\e
rror.js:29:11) at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Frank\Documents\CSE541\Project\flightdelaytracker\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:186:20) at Socket.g (events.js:292:16) at emitNone (events.js:86:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7) at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:342:8) at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5) name: 'MongoError', message: = 'connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out' }
```

Sample document:

```
> db.flights_jan2015.find().limit(1).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5848971edcb453cbc93274f1"),
        "id" : 468982,
        "year" : 2015,
        "quarter" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 12,
        "day_of_week" : 1,
        "unique_carrier" : "UA",
        "airline_id" : "19977",
        "carrier" : "UA",
        "origin_airport" : "TPA",
        "origin_city" : "Tampa",
        "origin_state" : "FL",
        "arrival_airport" : "CLE",
        "arrival_city" : "Cleveland",
        "arrival_state" : "OH",
        "scheduled_dep_time" : 1125,
        "actual_dep_time" : 1121,
        "true_dep_delay" : -4,
        "dep_delay" : 0,
        "dep_delay_15_flag" : 0,
        "taxi_out_time" : 13,
        "taxi_in_time" : 5,
        "schedule_arr_time" : 1356,
        "actual_arr_time" : 1342,
        "true_arr_delay" : -14,
        "arr_delay" : 0,
        "arr_delay_15_flag" : 0,
        "cancelled_flag" : 0,
        "air_time" : 123,
        "distance" : 927,
        "carrier_delay" : 0,
        "weather_delay" : 0,
        "nas_delay" : 0,
        "security_delay" : 0,
        "late_aircraft_delay" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it returns the count:

```
/*jslint node:true */
'use strict';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cse541';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    var collection = db.collection("flights");

    collection.count({year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1}).then(function (number) {
        console.log(number);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Show me what happens and we'll continue from there.

Edit: Let's make sure we can get you connected to mongodb

Try this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cse541';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: No Dice.

PS C:\Users\Frank\Documents\CSE 541\Project\flightdelaytracker> node serverside
Connected correctly to server
(node:19148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out
(node:19148) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not h
andled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: So right now you can't connect to your database at all.  See if you can get that connected first.  Try my above edit for a barebones example.  Just to be sure... you did run an npm install and have mongodb in your package.json dependencies right?

Comment: Oh just to be clear I can connect. I changed my db and my collections name and the above example works fine.

Also, if I use a cursor to limit the result to just one document, it also works.
My problem occurs when I get back a huge amount of documents.

And yes, I did run an npm install on mongodb with package.json.

Comment: A count should work fine though since you are only returning a number via memory.  Can you perform a count on the collection in your Mongo shell?

Comment: It took a good full 5-6 mins but it got done from the shell....

  > db.flights.count({year:2015,month:1,day:1})
  13930
  >

Comment: Maybe I need to config the mongodb driver or mongodb itself to allow these connections/queries to go over a certain amount of time?

I tried querying from R and I also have the same issue.
> library(mongolite)
> m=mongo(collection = "flights", db = "cse541")
> m$count('{"year":2015,"month":1,"day":1}')
Error: Failed to send "count" command with database "cse541": Failed to read 36 bytes from socket within 300000 milliseconds.
> library(mongolite)
> m=mongo(collection = "flights", db = "cse541")
> #m$count('{"year":2015,"month":1,"day":1}')
> m$count()
[1] 71672206

Comment: If there is no way to do this then I probably might have to split the data up into different collections...

Comment: Can you post a sample document?  I can use a for loop to try and duplicate this on my end.

Comment: Ive edited the original question to include a sample document. I think you need at least 1 million documents to reproduce the issue.